# PuTTY on Windows 10 showing Connection Timed Out

Tags: windows-10, ssh, putty

I installed PuTTY on windows 10 to connect to a workstation. On entering the IP address it remains idle for a while and says Fatal Error, Connection Timed Out. I tried disabling my firewall and turning off my anti-virus(K7 total security) but still no use. Can anybody help resolve this issue? Another friend of mine was able to connect without any hindrance, even he has windows 10.

Comment: Maybe there's a firewall between you and the host you're trying to connect to that's not forwarding port 22.

Comment: Are you able to ping that ip ?

Comment: There could be any number of possibilities... firewall on either client or server, network configuration between you and your colleague (VLAN, routing etc.)...

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, please refer https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask will help you to maintain the quality & standards of the community while asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Check, If you can establish `TCP Connection` on **`port 22`**`(ssh server)` or whatever configured.

When opening PuTTY :

- Input the `hostname` of the ssh server
- but change the `Connection type` to **`Telnet`** and port number to **`22`**.

You should see some greeting message from the ssh server.